# confused why IEnumerable to working invalid argument

Tags: c#, .net, linq, io, ssis

Hi I am having some trouble  I have a very simple script task in SSIS. This is the first time i used LINQ

```
string iFileName = (string)(Dts.Variables["iFileName"].Value);
string oFileName = (string)(Dts.Variables["oFileName"].Value);

try
{
   // string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"\\Fcwdsqlanl01\e$\SQL_OLAP\Log\Billing_2.log");

    IEnumerable<string> stringsOut = File.ReadAllLines(iFileName)
          .Where(line => (char.IsDigit(line, 0)) && line.Contains(","))
          .Select(line => line);

    File.WriteAllLines(oFileName, stringsOut);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}
```

this is the error I am getting

> The best overloaded match for 'System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(string,
>   string[])' has som invalid arguments.

I dont understand why its having a problem with the argument since I used it the same way as ReadAllLines.  Ive already checked and the stringsOut variable is holding the array of strings I want.  I realize there are ways of doing this not using WriteAllLines but I want to do that assuming Im missing something simple.

Comment: You may need to use the overload that takes a `String[]` (just call `ToArray()` at the end) since the [`IEnumerable<string>` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383693.aspx) was new in .NET 4. What framework version are you using?

Comment: I'll never understand why people use SSIS and do all of the work in a script task

Comment: Your `Select` method isn't doing anything; it should just be removed.

Comment: @msmucker and how would you do this specific taks without a script component?  Would you use the built in "Run through file and format it before sending to connection manager" Component?

Comment: Thanks Servy that I will do

Comment: @Tim Schmelter thanks man

Comment: @Mike_L should be able to do this in a DataFlow task with a conditional split, but perhaps i'm mistaken... Don't forget to select a correct answer once you get it fixed

Comment: @msmucker No, you cant conditional split until after you read it in from the connection manager.  There needs to be some formatting in a connection manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WriteAllLines` expects a `string[]` as its second argument, while you pass an `IEnumerable<string>`. That `IEnumerable<string>` could refer to a `string[]`, but could also refer to any other type also implementing `IEnumerable<string>`.

This should work:

```
File.WriteAllLines(oFileName, stringsOut.ToArray());
```

Comment: "In this particular case that IEnumerable<string> happens to refer to a string[],"  I cannot agree with this statement.  The `stringsOut` variable does not reference a `string[]` at all.

Comment: @juharr: so correct! I was rethinking that sentence while writing it and had a concurrency issue in my brain, one might say. Will correct it promptly.

Answer (score 2):

Which version of .Net are you compiling for?  The `WriteAllLines` overload which accepts an `IEnumerable<string>` as the second parameter wasn't added until .Net 4.0.  The method exists in 3.0 but only has the overload which takes a `string[]` as the second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Although you are doing a `ReadAllLines`, you are applying LINQ filters, which transforms this to an `IEnumerable<string>`.

Try changing your code to something like

```
IEnumerable<string> stringsOut = File.ReadAllLines(iFileName)
                  .Where(line => (char.IsDigit(line, 0)) && line.Contains(","))
                  .Select(line => line)
                  .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

> The best overloaded match for 'System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(string, string[])'

I assume you are below .NET 4, `WriteAllLines` with  [`IEnumerable<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383693.aspx) was new in .NET 4.

So just use the array version:

```
string[] stringsOut = File.ReadAllLines(iFileName)
    .Where(line => (char.IsDigit(line, 0)) && line.Contains(","))
    .Select(line => line)
    .ToArray();
File.WriteAllLines(oFileName, stringsOut);
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `File.WriteAllLines` does take string array as the second parameter and not a string

Comment: [File.WriteAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3.aspx) takes a `string[]` as second parameter. Was the "not" unintentional here?

Comment: Yes, I did not mean to type 'not' there. Thanks mate